# Opening a workbook using xlwings

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba, xlwings

I open a workbook with the script:

```
import xlwings as xw
std_path_str = r'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\XXX\EG_ReviewSTD_HN.xlsx'
std_wb = xw.Book(std_path_str)
```

The code runs successfully.

I modified the code so I don't need to change the `std_path_str` every time I move the script to a new folder:

```
import xlwings as xw
import os
current_dir_path = os.getcwd()
std_path_str = current_dir_path +  r'\EG_ReviewSTD_HN.xlsx'
std_wb = xw.Book(std_path_str)
```

There is an error:
[image]

I tried many ways but have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if your file is in the current working directory you dont need get the directory location in current_dir_path, just pass the file name like

```
xw.Book('Your_File_Name.xlsx')
```